# Is the problem the onclick method or the represenation of the html element as a object

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and this has been driving me nuts for the last hour

Here's the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Number Guessing Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
        <p>Greetings hominid. I've selected a number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or fewer. I'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.</p>
        <label for="guess">Enter your guess:</label>
        <input id="guess">
        <button id ="submit">Submit</button>
        <p id="response"></p>
        <p id="guess-count"></p>
        <p id="previous-guesses"></p>    
        
        <script src = scripts/game.js ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the javascript

```
const submitButton= document.getElementById('submit')

alert('hi')

submitButton.onClick = function submitGuess() { 
    
    alert('button is live')

  }
```

For some reason the submitGuess function is not being executed at all (at least I'm not seeing the alert). I had a lot more javascript but I reduced it to find out why it wasn't working.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `onClick` ?? it's `onclick` . And BTW don't use on* handlers at all. Use Element.addEventListener() instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Since this was caused by a smaller typo, you can delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you can add the event handler in the JavaScript via [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), rather than the inline HTML attribute. For example:

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', event => {
  console.log(`${event.target.id} was clicked`)
});
```

```html
<h1>Number Guessing Game</h1>
<p>Greetings hominid. I've selected a number between 1 and 100. See if you can guess it in 10 turns or fewer. I'll tell you if your guess was too high or too low.</p>
<label for="guess">Enter your guess:</label>
<input id="guess">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="response"></p>
<p id="guess-count"></p>
<p id="previous-guesses"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit')
```

this line get the value before the DOM fully loaded the solution is to define the const after the page load like this

```
window.onload = function(){
    const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit')
    alert('hi')
    if(submitButton){
        submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert("Clicked!");
        });
    }else{
        alert("Something Wrong")
    }
}
```